# Terraform docker cannot authenticate with container registry for remote host

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-docker

I am on a Windows machine using Terraform 0.13.4 and trying to spin up some containers on a remote host using Terraform and the Docker provider:

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://myvm:2376/"

  registry_auth {
    address = "myregistry:443"
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
  }

  ca_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/ca.pem"))
  cert_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/cert.pem"))
  key_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/key.pem"))
}

data "docker_registry_image" "mycontainer" {
  name = "myregistry:443/lvl1/lvl2/myimage:latest"
}
```

I am having a hard time with this as it cannot authenticate with my private registry. Always getting `401 Unauthorized`.

If I don't do this to grab the `sha256_digest` and just use the `docker_container` resource, everything works but it forces replacements of the running containers.

Comment: Hello do you have  problem with the authentification or the problem is the force replacements of the running containers.

Comment: The actual problem is the force replacements. If I use the named image ID in my `docker_container` resource it always "forces replacement". If I switch to the `sha256 digest` of my image this doesn't happen. However to get that I need to logon to the registry using the code shared, unless there is another way which I am not aware.

Comment: i think you missed the docker_image resource  iposted the answer you can check it

Comment: I saw it but doesn't stop from authenticating with the registry. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Angelos if you dont want to force replace  the running container you should try this :

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://myvm:2376/"

  registry_auth {
    address = "myregistry:443"
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
  }

  ca_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/ca.pem"))
  cert_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/cert.pem"))
  key_material = file(pathexpand(".docker/key.pem"))
}
data "docker_registry_image" "mycontainer" {
  name = "myregistry:443/lvl1/lvl2/myimage:latest"
}

resource "docker_image" "example" {
  name = data.docker_registry_image.mycontainer.name
  pull_triggers = [data.docker_registry_image.mycontainer.sha256_digest]
  keep_locally = true
}
```

then in the container  use :

```
resource "docker_container" "example" {
  image = docker_image.example.latest
  name = "container_name"
   
}
```

you shoukd use

```
docker_image.example.latest
```

Using the resource docker_image itself if it already exist he wont pull the image and doesn't restart the container but if you pass the name as a string he will replace the container everytime.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/container.html

Comment: even if the image is locally pulled on that host, the code like this still tries to authenticate with the registry, thus stopping at the same error. I tried skipping the `docker_registry_image` resource and get the `sha256_digest` from the `docker_image` resource but it is not available.

Comment: You need the authentification don't remove it but using  docker_image resource  and passing **.latest** to the docker_container will not recreate the container

Comment: But the authentication failing is still blocking if the only way to get the `sha256_digest` is using the `docker_registry_image` resource. Currently it fails before trying to pull the image.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the code is correct and that the container service I am using (older version of ProGet) is not replying correctly for the auth calls. I tested the code using another registry and it all works as expected.